# Vim nerdtree not able to open files

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I am trying to setup NerdTree on Unix. When I open gvim editor it displays the file explorer bar on the side. However, I am not able to click and open files nor use the vim keys. Not sure what's going on here.

I have the following lines in my vimrc for NerdTree setup:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
nmap <silent> <c-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 30
```

Any ideas? THanks.

Comment: Where's your cursor? `<CTRL-W>+H` will move it to the NERDTree window.

Comment: Not really answering your problem, but have you tried Command-t? Unless you really need to see your actual project tree (I just open files): https://github.com/wincent/Command-T

Answer (score 1):

In my system, nerdtree is easy to use.

just delete

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
nmap <silent> <c-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 30
```

and try in cmdline :NERDTreeToggle

and then map the cmd.